# Gradient TextField ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, gradient

I have been searching for a way to put gradient colors on TextField component for the past few hours with no luck. One method is to create a gradient rectangle and set the TextField as a mask for it but I can't make it work:

```
var m:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var mTxt:Sprite = new Sprite();
var txt:TextField = new TextField();
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var dropShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(); 

dropShadow.distance = 0;
dropShadow.angle = 120;
dropShadow.color = 0x000000;
dropShadow.alpha = 1;
dropShadow.blurX = 2;
dropShadow.blurY = 2;
dropShadow.strength = 1;
dropShadow.quality = 80;
dropShadow.inner = false;
dropShadow.knockout = false;
dropShadow.hideObject = false;
txt.filters = new Array(dropShadow); 


tf.font = "Ethnocentric Rg";
tf.color = 0xffde00;
tf.size = 72;
txt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
txt.text = "1756.25";
mTxt.addChild(txt);

var fillType:String = GradientType.LINEAR;
var colors:Array = [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF];
var alphas:Array = [1, 1];
var ratios:Array = [0x00, 0xFF];
var matr:Matrix = new Matrix();

matr.createGradientBox(400, 100, 0, 0, 0);

var spreadMethod:String = SpreadMethod.REFLECT;


m.graphics.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matr, spreadMethod);  
m.graphics.drawRect(0,0,400,120);

m.mask = mTxt;

addChild( m );
```

This code literally crashes the AIR debugger and exits itself. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set both layers' cacheAsBitmap option to true:

```
txt.cacheAsBitmap = true;
m.cacheAsBitmap = true;
addChild( m );
addChild(txt);
m.mask = txt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set cacheAsBitmap to true and make sure you're adding the mask to the stage.

```
m.cacheAsBitmap = mTxt.cacheAsBitmap = true;
m.mask = mTxt;
addChild( m );
addChild( mTxt );
```